# How to add first child to an Array-List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an array or a list with the first childs of a GameObject so I can edit them from another scripts.

I have tried it doing an Array, but it will take the childs of this childs too and I need to take only the first ones.

I have tried also with a List with a foreach, but it will add the same element every frame to the list, and I only need it one time.

```
public GameObject GOGranjaTerrain;
public GameObject GOFabricaTerrain;
public GameObject GOOficinaTerrain;

public Transform[] granjaTerrainArray;
public Transform[] fabricaTerrainArray;
public Transform[] oficinaTerrainArray;

public List<Transform> granjaTerrainList = new List<Transform>();

void Update()
{
    SearchTerrains1();
    SearchTerrains2();
}

//Array way
void SearchTerrains1()
{
    granjaTerrainArray = GOGranjaTerrain.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    fabricaTerrainArray = GOFabricaTerrain.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    oficinaTerrainArray = GOOficinaTerrain.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
}

//List way
void SearchTerrains2()
{
    foreach(Transform child in GOGranjaTerrain.transform)
    {
        granjaTerrainList.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GOGranjaTerrain.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        Transform child = GOGranjaTerrain.transform.GetChild(i);
        if (granjaTerrainList.Contains(child) == false)
        {
            granjaTerrainList.Add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better, if you only need to do it once - do in in Start instead of Update.

Comment: The problem its that I need to check it every time, since I will instantiate more childs

Comment: Ok, @AxelVelasco, I understand now. I've updated the code in my answer to do exactly that. Please check above.